# Add Information to Case Tab

Tags: standard-objects

WE are building a custom application on the SF platform, not related to the typical sales use case.

We are using the Case object to track work that we do.  Internally, we already assign a unique ID to each unit of work that corresponds to a case record.

When we display the Cases tab in SF, in the pull down menu currently we only show the case number generated by SF. (See attached.)  We would like to show both the case number and our internally-generated unique ID, which is the one that our employees are most familiar with.  (For various reasons we cannot only use this unique ID to refer to the case.)

Is there any way to modify the information shown in the Cases tab pull down menu to display a concatenation of case number and unique ID, like:  001234/AB-5631?

In search results we show both values (attached).
[image]

[image]